# How can i extract the correct countries codes and countries names from the link?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
public static void ExtractCountires()
        {
            try
            {
                htmltoextract = "http://sat24.com/en/?ir=true";
                client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadFile(htmltoextract, @"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                client.Dispose();

                string tag1 = "<li><a href=\"/en/";
                string tag2 = "</a></li>";

                string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(tag1));
                s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(tag2) + tag2.ToCharArray().Length);
                s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");

                string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { tag1, tag2 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                string tag3 = "<li><ahref=\"/en/";

                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 17)
                    {
                        //break;
                    }
                    string l = "";
                    if (parts[i].Contains(tag3))
                        l = parts[i].Replace(tag3, "");

                    string z1 = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf('"'));
                    if (!z1.Contains("</ul>"))
                    {
                        countriescodes.Add(z1);
                        countriescodes.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
                    }

                    string z2 = parts[i].Substring(parts[i].LastIndexOf('>') + 1);
                    if (z2.Contains("&amp"))
                    {

                    }
                    countriesnames.Add(z2);
                    countriesnames.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

In the first list countriescodes it's a global List in the original i had in index 17 number 17:  countriesnames in index 17 number 17 i have the country africa

So i'm not sure why in the countriescodes in index number 17 i'm getting

Like if the it's europe the code is eu or if the country name is turkey the code is tu.

The second problem is in the list of the countriesnames in two places i'm getting:

`Spain&amp;Portugal`

And

`UK&amp;Ireland`

And

`Romania&amp;Bulgaria`

What i want is just to remove the `&amp;` from this items.
So they will be for example UK & Ireland.

Comment: What do you mean by "What i want is just to remove the & from this items"? You provided an example of `UK&Ireland` and said that you want to have `UK & Ireland` instead. How is that "removing &"?

Comment: Do you actually want to split the string (UK/Ireland seperate) or just spaces around the & (as quetzalcoatl asked). Without this information we won't be able to help you

Comment: Ah it didn't add the &amp for some reason to my question. The Spain&Portugal and the two others are: Spain&amp;Portugal and i want to remove the &amp; or only the amp; from this three items and change them to: Spain & Portugal

Comment: If there's more to the question then what I answered you might want to re-do your question because I don't understand what you want with that top part about indexing at all.

Comment: @EpicKip I solved also the top part. Thanks.

Comment: @MosesMeteor Good :) No problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick example:

```
        string someCountryNames = "Ireland&amp;Brazil";
        if (someCountryNames.Contains("&amp;"))
        {
            someCountryNames = someCountryNames.Replace("&amp;", " & ");
        }
```

First you check if it contains the value you want to change (&amp in this case), if so you simply replace it as shown.